# Updating Grails 4+ configuration values during runtime

Tags: grails

In Grails 2 we used the "External configuration plugin", which included the method `checkNow()` for checking and refreshing values from an external config file.

Does it exist a simple approach for doing something similar in Grails 4+? I have seen references to Spring Cloud Config Server, but it seems a bit overkill for me. All I really want to do is be able to (now and then) update a config value in runtime. It could also be purely by a few lines of code, and does not have to originate from changes in the config file. This would avoid having to restart our server for minor changes in config. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'm replying to myself with a ridiculously simple answer: "just change it". Using the console plugin (or any other form of code execution), I can just assign `grailsApplication.config.any.property` a new value. It won't persist and it won't update any listeners or anything. But it is a glaringly obvious solution that I just assumed wouldn't work due to the `getProperty()` calls (I interpreted the name as reading from file) and googled discussions about Spring Cloud Config.

So, move on... nothing to see here. Just mild embarrassment :-P